# proper way to use chrome local storage

Tags: google-chrome-extension

i'm trying to use chrome.storage.local. but i'm having problems with the "set" method.
i'm sending 2 variables to the function named "setValue", one is `network` and the second is `value`. the porpose of the function is to use the `network` as key and the `value` as value.
when i'm trying to do this:

```
saveValue('c1','v1');

function saveValue(network,value)
{
    chrome.storage.local.set({network: value});
    // console.log(network);
}
```

everything look's ok. but when i'm tring to use `get` method im getting "undeffine"

```
printValue('c1');

function printValue(network)
{
    chrome.storage.local.get(network, function(data){
    console.log(data.network);
    });

}
```

Comment: In JavaScript `{network: value}` creates a key named `"network"`, not the contents of the variable, see [Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](//stackoverflow.com/q/2274242)

Comment: @wOxxOm i tried 
`function saveValue(network, value)
{

    chrome.storage.local.set({ [network]: [value] });
 console.log(network + "   " + value);

    
} 
function printValue(net)
{

 chrome.storage.local.get([net], function(data){
    console.log(data);
    });
 
}
 `
but still getting undefiend

Comment: `[network]` is correct, but `[value]` creates an array, which is not what you want.

Comment: Also, make sure to read about *asynchronous javascript* because chrome API is asynchronous so you have to read the value after it's actually written i.e. printValue should be invoked from a callback parameter of chrome.storage.local.set

Comment: @wOxxOm this only the testing stage, in the end i will store the data, and after ~30 sec i will read it. and if `value` is wrong, how do i use it correctly?

Comment: `[value]` is wrong, `value` is correct.

Comment: @wOxxOm ok nice. the saving is working, but the `get` method isn't.
`function printValue(net)
{

 chrome.storage.local.get(net, function(data){
    console.log(data.net);
    });
 
}
 `
im getting undefiend again :/

Comment: `data.net` retrieves a literal `"net"` key. You need `data[net]`. Make sure to read a tutorial on objects in JS.

Comment: @wOxxOm it's working! thank you :). 
but now i'm facing another problem. when i'm trying to store the `get` function into a var, nothing happen. i'm able to print it in `console.log`, but not to store it.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```js
chrome.storage.local.get({network: 'default'}, function(data){
    console.log(data.network);
});
```

might work:

```js
chrome.storage.local.get('network', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

first is better because you can set a default in case this key is still undefined.

Comment: wOxxOm answer already worked out for me :)
but now i'm facing another problem. when i'm trying to store the `get` function into a var, nothing happen. i'm able to print it in `console.log`, but not to store it.

Comment: the thing is, inside "get" your actually inside a callback function, so you cannot change the original scope. work with what you got inside the inner scope of "get".